# Invalid conversion from... Objective-C++

Tags: casting, objective-c++, static-cast

I just told Xcode to compile everything as Objective-C++ and now I have errors from casting.

```
void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (
                                       void                      *aInUserData,
                                       AudioSessionPropertyID    aInPropertyID,
                                       UInt32                    aInPropertyValueSize,
                                       const void                *aInPropertyValue
                                       ) {

    // Ensure that this callback was invoked because of an audio route change
    if (aInPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;

    // This callback, being outside the implementation block, needs a reference to the MixerHostAudio
    //   object, which it receives in the inUserData parameter. You provide this reference when
    //   registering this callback (see the call to AudioSessionAddPropertyListener).
    TJUSimpleSequencer *lAudioObject = (TJUSimpleSequencer *) aInUserData;

    // if application sound is not playing, there's nothing to do, so return.
    if (NO == lAudioObject.isPlaying) {

        NSLog (@"Audio route change while application audio is stopped.");
        return;

    } else {

        // Determine the specific type of audio route change that occurred.
        CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = aInPropertyValue; // !!! invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'const __CFDictionary*'

        CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef =
        CFDictionaryGetValue (
                              routeChangeDictionary,
                              CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason)
                              ); // !!! invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'const __CFNumber*'
```

When i try to use `static_cast<CFDictionaryRef>(aInPropertyValue)`, I get nothing. As though (which is probably true) I am not using it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular C cast?

```
CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = ( CFDictionaryRef )aInPropertyValue;
```

#### Edit 0:

How about this for that function call (if you're sure it's a number :)

```
CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef =
    ( CFNumberRef )CFDictionaryGetValue ( ...
```

#### Edit 1:

Take a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) then.

Comment: ok--that worked--why doesn't static cast work? Not that i REALLY want to use it, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'm not a Objective-C guy, but in C++ that'd be `reinterpret_cast<>` not a `static_cast<>`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have already started in on the C++ primer plus